# How can I start a standalone wiremock with stubs from spring-cloud-contracs?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I just would like to start a simple wiremock with the stubs from my spring cloud contract. There is a StubRunner class from Spring but the constructor makes no sense to me. It seems that the stubRunnerOptions contains all infos needed and I have no idea what I should provide for repositoryPath and stubsConfiguration.

```
 public StubRunner(StubRunnerOptions stubRunnerOptions, String repositoryPath, StubConfiguration stubsConfiguration)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with the following code:

```
 BatchStubRunner stubRunner = new BatchStubRunnerFactory(
                options).buildBatchStubRunner();
 RunningStubs runningCollaborators = stubRunner.runStubs();
```